# error when use multiple mpi_bcast

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have a problem with 3 mpi_bcast and one mpi_scatter, my program don't work well ,mpi_scatter don't work and globalparcsr don't scatter between nodes. when i delete second and third mpi_bcast ,mpi_scatter work well. I want broadcast a and globalindividual and globalfitness and then scatter globalparcsr, part of  my code as bellow:

```
int malloc2dint(int ***array, int n, int m) {

/* allocate the n*m contiguous items */
int *p = (int *)malloc(n*m * sizeof(int));
if (!p) return -1;

/* allocate the row pointers into the memory */
(*array) = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
if (!(*array)) {
    free(p);
    return -1;
}

/* set up the pointers into the contiguous memory */
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    (*array)[i] = &(p[i*m]);

return 0;
}


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


int size, rank, divided_pop_size, sum = 0, root = 0, procgridsize, sum2 = 0,generation=0;
int **globalindividual, **localindividual;
int *globalfitness, *localfitness;
int *globalparcsr, *localparcsr;
int **recbuf;
int *sendcounts, *parsendcount;     //specifying the number of elements to send to each processor
int *displs, *pardispls;         //Entry i specifies the displacement   
MPI_Status status;
int offset, rows;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

divided_pop_size = n_initial_pop / size;


if (rank == root)
{


    malloc2dint(&globalindividual, n_initial_pop, num_vertices);
    read_graph();

    globalfitness = (int*)malloc(n_initial_pop * sizeof(int));
    globalparcsr = (int*)malloc(n_initial_pop * sizeof(int));

    globalindividual = initial_population(globalindividual, n_initial_pop);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_initial_pop; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < num_vertices; j++)
            printf("%d", globalindividual[i][j]);
    }


}
for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {

    if (rank == p) {
        malloc2dint(&localindividual,n_initial_pop + 2, num_vertices);
        localindividual = initial_population(localindividual, divided_pop_size + 2);
    }
}



    MPI_Bcast(&a[0][0], 5000 * 5000, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&globalindividual[0][0], n_initial_pop*num_vertices, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast(&globalfitness, n_initial_pop, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);




MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

a is a 2d array and globalindividual is a 2d array with 12 rows and 8 columns and globalfitness is 1d array with size 12

please help me.

Comment: Please, post full source of program which fails.

Comment: Remove `&` in `MPI_Bcast(&globalfitness, ...)`.

Comment: I remove & and define globalfitness as a static array int globalfitness[n_initial_pop];and problem solved but I want to use dynamic array in my program but do it cause to fail program, why?

Comment: You allocate memory for `globalindividual` and `globalfitness` only in the master process due to `if (rank == root)`. This might be one of the reasons of getting seg fault.

Comment: Also this is why allocating on the stack instead of the heap solves your problem as you verified.

Comment: thank you so much, it's solved.